# side by side image in qt scrollbar

Tags: qt, qimage, qscrollarea

I have written the code below in order to view an image in the Qt scroll area Widget.

```
void ImageViewer::open(){
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                 tr("Open File"), QDir::homePath());
if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
     QImage image(fileName);
     if (image.isNull()) {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Image Viewer"),
                                  tr("Cannot load %1.").arg(fileName));
         return;
     }
     imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
     scaleFactor = 1.0;

     printAct->setEnabled(true);
     fitToWindowAct->setEnabled(true);
     updateActions();

     if (!fitToWindowAct->isChecked())
         imageLabel->adjustSize();
  }
 }
```

now I want to see two or three pictures in a scroll area but unfortunately, I don't know what the function is or how can I put three images side by side in a single scroll area.

Comment: Use QListWidget instead QLabels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356319/how-to-filter-image-files-from-selected-directory-which-is-inside-listwidget/51356851#51356851

Comment: you mean there is not any way to use QLabels?

Comment: yes you can but the easiest thing is to use QListWidget

Comment: In SO and on the internet there are a lot of examples of QScroolBar, review them, modify them and when you try something you just post a question, in SO we will not do your work, read [ask]